# What if the snap I want is not available and I can't use apt?

Tags: snap, ubuntu-core

There's a huge variety of packages available via `apt`, especially when third party repositories are considered, but from what I can see, there are far fewer snaps available.

For example, I've looked in the [store](https://snapcraft.io/store), and OpenCV is not there, but `apt search opencv` returns a long list of packages.

I've just started using an edge server with Ubuntu Snappy Core pre-installed and when I run `apt` it tells me:

> Ubuntu Core does not use apt-get, see 'snap --help'!

and running `snap --help` doesn't tell me how to install something when the snap isn't available.

I've googled quite a bit to see if there's a standard way of installing a package (presumably as a snap) if the snap's not already available, but I can't find anything.  Do I have to add repositories like with `apt`?

I wondered if `snap search opencv` might yield results that the store doesn't but, it seems to be the same single-item list.

Comment: Thanks, I saw the link that's in the comment but it sounded like it was for people developing new snaps so I didn't pay it too much attention!  However, the classic snap could well be what I'm looking for thanks.

Comment: So you might want to write 2 lines as answer, and set is as solution?

Answer (score 0):

There kind of is a way of using apt but thats not either recommended or what core has been design for. If you want to test it try below:

**!! Run at your own risk !!**

```
snap install classic --edge --devmode
sudo classic
```

Then:

```
(classic)$ sudo apt install something
```

Comment: Thanks.  I tried that in response to @dsstorefile's comment above, and whilst it gets partway to where I need to be, it's too restrictive for my needs because it uses `chroot`.

Comment: @IpsRich So, what did you end up doing to get around the restriction?  Thanks!

Comment: @stdcerr I looked back through my notes from four years ago, and it turns out I abandoned Ubuntu Core Snappy and installed standard Ubuntu (16.04 at the time).  Probably not what you were hoping for - sorry!

Comment: @IpsRich all good, thanks for checking! :)